# increase cell count without increasing data in table of iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

my data set is like

```
var data = [["1"],["2","3"],["4"]]
```

and I want to show it in table view
which I am able to using

```
cell.textlabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

I have a button in navigation bar which when I click should increment all the sections row by 1 without changing anything in data
and all the newly created cell textfield should say "add here"

my cell for rowat

```
let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
cell.textlabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
return cell
```

how should I change my cell for row at so that I don't get fatal error index out of range

Comment: “should increment all the sections row by 1 without changing anything in data” - Are you saying that each section gets one new row? Or that you get one new section? And what do you mean about by “without changing anything in data”? That doesn’t make sense. When you want to change the UI, you always have to change the model. Now maybe that view’s model isn’t saved into some broader model or persistent store yet, but you always have to change the local model...

Comment: I want to add a new row to each section I am sorry for not being clear, I am new here

Comment: share your cellForRowAt

Comment: I have edited the question to add my cell for rowat

Comment: I want something like when you press edit button when you are seeing someones contact detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @iOSArchitect.com 's answer,
You should check the index in cellForRowAt.
The reason you are getting index out of range exception is because your numberOfCell count increases but the cell's data source remains the same.

So,

```
let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
if indexPath.row < data[indexPath.section].count{
cell.textlabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
}else{
cell.textlabel?.text = "add here"
}
return cell
```

This may not be the precise code but I hope you get the logical answer out of this.

Comment: And there's an interesting question as to whether he really wants to use the same cell type, or whether he might just have a different cell prototype for the "add here" cells.

Comment: @Rob yes you're right i have edited the answer..probably would have figured it out at runtime smh..
Of course the 'different cell for ''add here'' ' can go inside the `else` statement if the op chooses to.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable named extraRows and assign its initial value as 0 and add a property observer to it so that whenever it changes, it reloads the tableView

```
var extraRow : Int = 0 { 
  didSet { 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

After the click of the add button, update extraRow to + 1

```
@IBAction func addBtnClicked(_ sender : Any) { 
  extraRow = extraRow + 1 
}
```

Also, update your number of rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return data.count + extraRows 
}
```

Along with this, you also need to update your tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath and place a check for `if indexPath.row > data.count` , then show your empty celll

Comment: I am able to do that but the problem is I am not able to show data in the table view

Comment: @AsminGhale what difference does it make?

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com sorry i should have read the question more carefully. I will delete my useless comment.

Comment: I would not recommend `reloadData`. I'd suggest [inserting the rows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows). E.g. `let indexPaths = data.map { IndexPath(row: $0.count, section: 0) }` and `tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .middle)`.